# How do I know if part of a given string is a string in a Arraylist<String>?

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I'm doing a homework assignment and I'm having a hard time trying to find out how to figure out if part of a given String is a string in an `Arraylist` of String.

Example of given string:

```
loveaspd
asdhouseaspd
```

arraylist of string: love, house, home, dog, amuse, problem...

I have tried to use contains but just realized it will not help me once I have to check each letter.

Example: `loveaspr`

my program is supposed to check the word `love`, so it will see if the first letter matches and go to the second letter. So, after reading the word `love`, the output will be:

```
love exists.
```

The the program will check the letter `a`. There is a word with the letter `a` in my arrayList so it will check the second letter and will see that there is no such word where the first letter is `a` and the second is `s`. then `a` will be rejected and `s` will be rejected.

The last part of the string will be checked (note that I have the word problem in my arrayList, so the program will check the first and second letter and then both will be rejected together).

Therefore, my output should be:

```
love exists.
a rejected.
s rejected.
pr rejected.
```

The problem is that I don't know how to check each letter in each word of my ArrayList. I'm not asking for someone to code my homework for me. I'm looking for someone who could say which topic I should study (specifically) or give an example of something related to my issue in order to complete the task (it is due tomorrow).

Thanks in advance,

Ian Pierre.

Comment: What have you tried so far and where are you stuck? You can't expect the community to just solve the problem for you

Comment: The problem is I don't really know where to start. I tried to use string.contains but it will not help me since I have to check letter by letter.

Comment: use if **list.contains("word")** will return either true of false that's it

Answer (score 0):

Go on like this

```
ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String a : ar) {
            if (a.contentEquals("any_string_here") || a.equalsIgnoreCase("any_string_here")) {
                System.out.println("Found");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but I don't think it would help me. I just edited my question. Could you please read it again?

Comment: @IanPierre can you give a sample of correct input and the expected output...?

Comment: my dictionary, for example: house, love, home, problem, amuse.               Given input: loveprhomedc                                                                                    expected output: love exists, pr doesnt exist, home exists, d doesnt exist, c doenst exist.             (Note that the program should search words with the first letter, then the second letter, just like I real dictionary I would say)

Comment: @IanPierre sorry but didn't get that one. Explain a little bit

Comment: I hit enter by mistake, sorry.

Comment: @IanPierre ok i get that you want to search these words in an input string....but explain the manner of searching...

Comment: If I had "probles" as input using the same dictionary as the last example. The output should be: probles doesn't exist (because 6 letters match with problem) but if the output was "miss" the output should be m doesnt exist, i doenst exist, s doesnt exist, s doesnt exist because I don't have any word starting with m, or i, or s.

Comment: @IanPierre I would suggest you to go with string methods. You can see the samples at websites like www.tutorialspoint.com or the oracle website for complete java docs...

Comment: Alright, dude. I will surely look it up. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to iterate the list, and use `String.indexOf()` to determine partial matches. Here is an example:

```
  private static String match(List<String> mots, String searchPhrase) {
        for(String mot : mots) {
            if(searchPhrase.indexOf(mot) >= 0) {
                return mot;
            }
        }
        return "No Match Found.";
    }

    //Test
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> mots = new ArrayList<>();
        mots.add("un");
        mots.add("deux");
        mots.add("trois");
        String searchPhrase = "lesdeuxchats";
        System.out.println( match(mots,searchPhrase) );  //Output = "deux"
    }
```

Comment: the method indexOf() checks each letter?

Comment: It checks each letter until it finds the String it's looking for, or until the end of the character sequence is reached.  Here is the Javadoc on it: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

```
String s;
ArrayList<String> list= new ArrayList<String>();
int i,j;

for(i=0;i<s.length;i++)
{
    for(j=i+1;j<s.length;j++){
        if(list.contains(s.substring(i,j)){
            System.out.println("The list contains "+s.substring(i,j));
        }
    }
}
```

Substrings (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_substring.htm) are the way to get parts of your original string.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SO {       
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
        al.add("ABC");
        al.add("DEF");
        al.add("GHI");
        al.add("JKL");
        al.add("MNO");

        for (String arrList : al) {
            if(arrList == "GHI"){
                System.out.println("Found");
            }
        }
        }       
    }
```